# NGINX api routes 404 not found

Tags: nginx, routes

NGINX doesn't see the routes, giving `404 NOT FOUND`.
The website is located in `/usr/share/nginx/html/website` folder and accessed via `http://localhost`.

The route I'm accessing in the application is `localhost/api/public/languages`.

Here is my NGINX:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html/website;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;

        error_log /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log;

   }
```

How to access the routes?

Comment: Do your routes end with `.php`?

Comment: @ErvalhouS No, just 'languages', 'accounts', etc. They are defined in api/routes/web.php